# how to call an angular controller function using a parameter value that is just rendered in the current view?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I rewrote parts of my code to make it simpler to understand, so bear with me through the code, I'm only writing the part that's causing the problem.

I have a mean.js application, the backend is sorted with express and mongodb, all my resource endpoints are working well independently, but now I'm viewing objects that have complex schemas, so lets say objA holds a value of ObjectId for objB

whenever I try to retreive ObjB by Id from inside the ObjA view, I call the $resource factory for a getObjectBbyID, but I can't find a value in my current $scope that I can use to store the value just rendered by ng-bind in ObjA html view

mongoose model

```
var objASchema = new Schema({
name:{
type: string
},
myobjB:{
type: Schema.ObjectId,
ref: 'ObjectB'
}
)};
mongoose.model('ObjectA', objASchema);
```

in my angular front-end there's a $resource factory that gets $resource by Id

```
angular.module('objbmodule').factory('ObjectBs', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
            return $resource('api/objbs/:objbId',{
                objbId: '@_id'
            }, {
            update:{
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
}]);
```

finally in my view I'm trying to retrieve the objectB by Id, inside the view of ObjectA findOne()

```
angular.module('objas').controller('ObjAController', ['$scope',$routeParams','ObjectBs' function($scope, $routeparams, ObjectBs){
$scope.findOne=function(){
$scope.obja= ObjectAs.get({
objaId: $routeParams.objaId
});
};

$scope.findObjB=function(someid){
if(!someid)
console.log("noid");
$scope.objb = ObjectBs.get({
objbId: someid
});
};
}
]);
```

now the problem lies here that in this one view i need to call 2 factory GET methods, the first one using ID provided in the original $routeParam from my application route point of view, and the second using objbId value that is rendered when the first ObjA is retrieved.

```
<div ng-controller="ObjAController" ng-init"findOne()">
<span ng-bind="obja.name">{{obja.name}}</span>
<span ng-bind="obja.objbId">{{obja.objbId}}
<span ng-init="findObjB(obja.objbId)" ng-bind="objb.name">
</div>
```

I can't find a possible ng directive that can evoke my controller method using the Id value just rendered in this view, because it only exists in the rendered html,

Comment: I'm not sure the question is completely clear here.  if by "the Id value" you mean `obja.objId`, that is simply `$scope.obja.objbId`. `$scope` is implicit in the HTML, but these values still most definitely exist in the JS, not just in the rendered HTML.  Also, this isn't, strictly speaking, an appropriate use for `ng-init`.

Comment: Object a holds a value for Object b _id value, which I'm trying to use or hold somewhere in my frontend angular controller to use it with Object B factory to retrieve the object B by Id using the get factory. 
I'm using ng-init as the only way I'm sure will call the second function in my controller responsible for getting Object B document, without any user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your findOne function return a promise using $q as follows:

```
function findOne() {
    var config = {method: "get", url: prefix + "get", params: {id: id}};
    var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(ObjectAs.get({objaId: $routeParams.objaId}));
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

and then you can call a getOne function with your ng-init that uses that promise to execute the next functions you need to execute:

```
function getOne() {
    findOne()
        .then(function(response) {
            secondaryFunction1();
            secondaryFunction2();
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be easy to solve but from mongoose point of view to retrieve the right object from the database, and then from angular to bind to the correct value in the front end.

in my mongoose server controller

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
ObjectA = mongoose.model(ObjectA);

exports.objectAById = function(req, res, next, id){
//here i WAS populating('_id', 'objb') instead of what I have now which returns the whole objb Object wrapped inside the ObjectA JSON
ObjectA.findById(id).populate('objb')
.populate('name)
.exec(function(err, obja){
//error handling
```

in my html now I have

```
<span ng-bind="obja.objb.name"></span>
```

it was mainly about my backend findone method that needed tweaking. thanks for your contributions